# INotifyPropertyChanged doesn't work (UWP)

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I need to refresh `Image` on `View` 
This my ViewPage:

```
<Image Grid.Row="1"
Grid.Column="1" 
x:Name="OriginalImg"
Source="{Binding Orig}"
DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}"/>
```

I'm using MVVMLibs package. And This is my ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    private WriteableBitmap original = new WriteableBitmap(1280,720);
    private WriteableBitmap temp = new WriteableBitmap(1280,720);

    public WriteableBitmap Orig
    {
        get { return original; }
        set
        {
            this.original = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChanged("Orig");
        }
    }
    public async Task<bool> ApplyEffectAsync(StorageFile file)
    {
      fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
      temp.SetSource(fileStream);
      Orig = temp;
    }
}
```

But `Image` on my Page not displayed. What's my problem?

Comment: Where is `ApplyEffectAsync` called?

Comment: Its called in another class with `ICommand` and this method work correctly. And next VS goes to my setter and call `RaisePropertyChanged ` but nothing displayed on View

Comment: Im posted it. Im use `Source="{Binding Orig}"`

Comment: Okay just so we are clear, I use INotifyPropertyChanged in UWP all the time. It works lol... Second, what does your output window say? Is there any BindingExpression Errors? What is the actual source path for the image?

Comment: I dont have any errors or exceptions. I use `FilePicker` for open my image then put it to `StorageFile` and with `FileStream` put to `WriteableBitmap `

Comment: @AnthonyRussell From the endless discussion on my now deleted answer to this question it became clear that OP has multiple view model instances, at least one declared as XAML resource (and used as binding source) and another created in code behind on which the ApplyEffectAsync method is called. I tried to explain why this wouldn't work, though without success.

Comment: @Clemens ehhh oh okay thank you for the heads up

Comment: im created just 1 instance of VM in XAML then i delete it and wrote in code behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you are not really instantiating a new WriteableBitmap, just changing its source. So while it might work the first time, it certainly won't work after because the Dependency Property Manager won't know that your image changed unless its instace changes.

Try creating your temp WriteableBitmap in the ApplyEffectAsync method.